# Does a shortage of Uranium affect nukes' strength?

Tags: civilization-5

When you have a negative quantity of some strategic resource all military units using that resource get a penalty to their combat strength until you get the balance back to zero or above.

I was wondering if nukes also suffer some sort of strength reduction when you don't have enough Uranium to maintain them.

Comment: Nuclear submarines maybe. No nukes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With nukes, it makes absolutely zero difference.

[image]

Notice that in this instance, I've got 3 Uranium spare. I've just dropped a nuke on top of Genghis Khan's capital, taking off half its health.

[image]

In this second case, I have -1 Uranium left over and just dropped a nuke. It's left Karakorum with the same amount of health and the same number of citizens. It has also left the Mobile AA with 1HP in both cases, and my poor poor infantry with the same amount of HP.

Ergo, negative uranium makes no difference to *nukes*. I suspect it will impact on nuclear submarines, as they are a unit that hangs around (as opposed to a one-time usage unit).

Comment: As far as I know, the damage nuke inflicts on units has a random element (similar to how regular combat damage works), so I'm not sure a single strike is enough for science. I am pretty convinced, though.

Comment: I am convinced too. Notice how it did more damage to the troops when in negative. Poor Karkaorum, its Ground Hog day!

Comment: @Valamas: The infantry on the left hand side of the top picture aren't there because of the way I'd rigged this setup. In the bottom pic, the AI had moved them to a different spot, outside of the blast radius. They did not die.